# FileStream.Read not reading last 'chunk'

Tags: .net-3.5, filestream

I have an interesting scenario I hope someone else has stumbled upon. I am attempting to copy part of an open FileStream to separate file streamin c# .Net 3.5. Using the code below, I read 37 'chunks' of 4096 bytes but **fail to read the last 'partial chunk' of 3812 bytes**.

```
string filPath = "c:\aRatherSmallFileThatCouldBeQuiteLarge.log";
string tmpNam = Path.GetTempFileName();
using (FileStream wt = new FileStream(tmpNam, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (FileStream rd = new FileStream(filPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        long cutPosition = 65217;
        int bytesRead;
        int chunkSize = 4096;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
        while ((bytesRead = rd.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize)) != 0)
            wt.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    File.Copy(tmpNam, filPath, true);
}
File.Delete(tmpNam);
```

There are no errors produced; the final 3812 bytes are simply not written to the destination file as expected.

It's a small example, but I'm intending to use this on very large files...so solutions that read the source file into memory are not viable here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to move the `File.Copy` outside of the `using` blocks:

```
using (FileStream wt = new FileStream(tmpNam, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using (FileStream rd = new FileStream(filPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        ...
    } // closes the read stream
    // you're trying to move the file here, before the write stream is flushed out
} // closes the write stream (flushing out the last chunk)
// Do the copy after the write stream has been flushed and closed
File.Copy(tmpNam, filPath, true);
File.Delete(tmpNam);
```

You might be copying the file before the final write gets flushed out to the temporary file.

Comment: Thanks @Cory, but those are just in place to relay the intent of the code. Currently I'm just opening the tmp file and observing it is incomplete.

Comment: Are you doing something with `cutPosition` that we can't see in the above example? You don't use it here.

Comment: No, actually your first comment was quite right. I was breaking on a line before the writing stream closed...and thus before it's final flush. So many thanks. Answer accepted.